# Cloning table section within a form, using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table

I have a form in a table and there's a section within the table that I need to keep repeatable for the user so I can give him the oportunity to add more sections if he wishes to.

I'm doing this with JQuery.

Part of my HTML code is here:

```
            <div id="entry1" class="clonedInput">
                <tr>
                    <td class="title" align="right">
                        <div id="reference" name="reference" class="heading">TITLE</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><label class="label_ol" for="local">Observation       Local</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="local" class="input_ol" id="local" size="50"></td>

                    <td align="right"><label class="input_et" for="effect_type">Effect Type</label><br></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="effect_type" class="input_et" id="effect_type">
                            <option value="0">OPT1</option>
                            <option value="1">OPT2</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </div>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <div id="addDelButtons" align="right">
                        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Adicionar Reação">
                        <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="Remover Reação">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

My JQuery:

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {
    var num     = $(".clonedInput").length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added
        newElem = $("#entry" + num).clone().attr("id", "entry" + newNum).fadeIn("slow"); // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
                                                                                        // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
    // Título
    newElem.find(".heading").attr("id", "ID" + newNum + "_reference").attr("name", "ID" + newNum + "_reference").html("C2. Reaction no " + newNum);
    alert(newElem.find(".heading").html());
    // 1º Input
    newElem.find('.label_ol').attr('for', 'local' + newNum);
    newElem.find('.input_ol').attr('id', 'local' + newNum).attr('name', 'local' + newNum).val('');

    // 2º Input
    newElem.find('.label_et').attr('for', 'effect_type' + newNum);
    newElem.find('.input_et').attr('id', 'effect_type' + newNum).attr('name', 'effect_type' + newNum);

    // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
    $('#entry' + num).after(newElem);
    $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();

    // enable the "remove" button
    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);

    // right now you can only add 5 sections. change '5' below to the max number of times the form can be duplicated
    if (newNum == 5)
    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit.");
});
```

What I am trying to do is simply to clone the div that wraps the section that I want to repeat, give new attribute values to each of the inputs (so data doesn't get messed up in the database) and append the section after the "mother" div.
For some reason it's not working.
Thank you all in advance!

JSFiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ygqrf8tr/1/)

Comment: I've done something similar, what I found solved a lot of headaches is to 1) delegate any of your event listeners and 2) not assign names to your form fields, then in a submit event listener function iterate through the rows and assign names based on the rows.

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm sure that's the best approach but I didn't have much time to re-do all the code. Check the solution that I came up with, below.

Comment: If it works, it works.

Answer (score 0):

For the people wondering if I got a solution, I did, actually. far from the best solution but due to a deadline I needed to come along with a quick solution.

So, basically, instead of wrapping the block I wanted to repeat with a `<div>` and clone it as a whole, I just gave different id's to every set of `<tr></tr>`, clone the content of those sets, add the new elements together (using *.add()* method) and append the result after the last cloned set.
For some reason, this isn't working with a `<div>` and I don't know why.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6zj2utew/)'s the working JSFiddle.